# How can I interact with MongoDB via Mongoose without Express?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'd like an environment where I can get a solid grasp of how CRUD operations work. Up to this point, I've been using `views` to see how the data looks like but with the obvious inflexibility, this approach isn't that insightful -- it's something like driving in the dark.

Now I want to be able to work with the data in MongoDB via the functionality offered by Mongoose so that I see what actually happens when I do this or that, subdocuments, population, that sort of stuff. Initially, I had this code in a `script.js` file:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
// ...
// define schemas
// try some crazy things
// ...
console.log(results);
```

And then I attempted to execute that code:

`node script.js`

Which didn't work. I then tried:

```
mongo load('script.js')
```

This time, I got an error, of course -- `require()` is not defined. Facepalm.

Hopefully that gives you an idea of what I'm trying to do. I've since tried other methods that didn't seem to work.

Please advise.

**UPDATE**

And here's my `script.js` file:

```
var Hero = require('./hero-model');
// This hero-model.js file defines the schema
// and exports its functionality. I've used
// this model to successfully CRUD data
// via Express. You can ignore the code above
// where I stated require('mongoose') because I was
// merely simplifying. Running this script causes
// the command to terminate silently.

var getHeroes = function() {

    Hero.find(function(err, heroes) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
        console.log(heroes);
    });
};

getHeroes();
```

Comment: I checked that also. The app is indeed connected to its database.

Comment: Didn't I just mention that when I use Express, I can successfully get the docs to be output to the views? That means my database connection and collection is set up just right.

Comment: Found the problem and solved it. I had to move my scripts to a new app which did not have Express installed as a dependency. Actually, Mongoose is the only dependency defined in this new app's package.json file. And that worked.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to run a node script as a mongo shell script.  To run it as a regular node script, simply use:

```
node script.js
```

Comment: @FourEyedHawk What happens when you try?  Are you running the command from the same directory as `script.js`, and do you have all the necessary modules installed?

Comment: It's the same directory within the same app where I'm outputting data to the views. The console should output the same data but that's not the case -- the command silently terminates.

Comment: Can you show your entire file, then?  Silent termination is... irregular.

Comment: I've updated my question to include the script.js file.

Comment: Try logging some debug info. E.g., `console.log("about to call getHeroes();")`.  Something to just verify that the fundamentals of running the script are working.

Comment: Ah. I found the problem. I moved all my scripts to a new app which doesn't have Express installed as a dependency. Worked like a charm. Thanks for your time, though.

Comment: @FourEyedHawk Honestly that doesn't even make sense (at least not from the code you posted). Having express hanging around in the `node_modules` folder, as long as you never `require()` it, has no effect on your other code.

Comment: My bad. I should've picked my words more carefully. I meant that the first time, I used the Express generator -- `express heroes-app` -- to prepare my app files. This time I didn't.

Answer (score 0):

You can run node  to run nodejs without expressJs but I think we should install expressJs to cope with database