# Unable to query MongoDB using Mongoose outside REST API

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

This is driving me crazy.  The Express router works fine with Mongoose models but I can't use the models in other files without routes.  Every time I try running the file with the imported models or mongoose schema it returns blank in the console.  I am calling the function exactly the same way in the user router file.

```html
///////////////////////////////
//File: test.js (not working)//
///////////////////////////////

var user = require('./user');


user.getUserById({_id:'5c902f4c75d827057cc5ad17'}, function(err, user){
    if(err) return console.error(err);
    console.log(user);
});

////////////////////////////
//User model file: user.js//
////////////////////////////


var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;

mongoose.set('debug', true);

var bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');

const moment = require('moment');

var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({


    username: { type: String, required: true },
    email: { type: String, required: true },
    firstname: { type: String, required: true },
    lastname: { type: String, required: true },
    password: { type: String, required: true },
    chargeApiId: { type: String, required: false },
    address: { type: String, required: false },
    state: { type: String, required: true },
    county: { type: String, required: true },
    businessname: { type: String, required: false },
    updated_date: { type: String, default: moment(new Date()).format("DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss") },
    activated: {type: Boolean, required: false},
    active_sub: {type: String, required: false},
    lastlogin: { type: String, required: false },
    datecreated: { type: String, required: true }
  });

  var User = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);

module.exports = User;

module.exports.test = function(id, callback) {
  console.log('test');
  User.findById(id, callback);
}

module.exports.getUserById = function(id, callback) {
  User.findById(id, callback);
  
}

module.exports.getUserByUsername = function(username, callback) {
    const query = {username: username};
    User.findOne(query, callback);
}

// Method to compare password for login
module.exports.comparePassword = function (candidatePassword, res, callback) {
    bcrypt.compare(candidatePassword, res, (err, isMatch) => {
      if (err) { return callback(err); }
      callback(null, isMatch);
    });
  };

//password hashing
module.exports.bcyprtPw = function (password) {

    var salt = bcrypt.genSaltSync(10);
    var hash = bcrypt.hashSync(password, salt);
    console.log(hash);
    return(hash);
}
```

Edit: I found this article an it seems it may be a setting in mongoose itself.  Any ideas of how to do fix this?

[How can I interact with MongoDB via Mongoose without Express?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26264917/how-can-i-interact-with-mongodb-via-mongoose-without-express)

Comment: Can you share your code of the user.js

Comment: Any update on this?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should export your functions from file user.js as

```
module.exports = { User , test, getUserById , ..etc}
```

And import the required functions as

```
 const { User , test, getUserById } = require("./user.js");
```

You can refer to this answer also.

[Declare multiple module.exports in Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16631064/declare-multiple-module-exports-in-node-js)

Comment: Isn't this just creating custom methods for the schema?  I'm just trying to use the built in methods that came with mongoose.  They all work in my router file fine but I'm trying to use them without express in another file.

Comment: Please check, I have edited my answer as per your comment.

Comment: Still no result.  The thing that's interesting is the callback doesn't work for the methods.  I can't even console.log a random string inside it.  This is only for the mongoose methods, it's not specifically an export issue.

Comment: @AdrianCorey Were you able to debug this?